# Efficient way to convert/reinterpret vector<T> as vector<array<T, 1>>

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, stdarray

I want to call a method (template) that takes a `vector<array<T, N>>&` with the result from another method that returns a `vector<T>`

Is there a efficient (O(1)) way to reinterpret a `vector<T>` as a `vector<array<T,1>>`? Is it possible / safe to `reinterpret_cast` it?

Comment: @timrau aren't both containers supposed to store the elements contiguously?

Comment: @timrau sure you cannot access it? imho the underlying vector::data array should be a continous piece of memory of size capacity * sizeof(T) bytes in either case. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @b.buchhold Unfortunately, `std::array` is not guaranteed not to have something at the end of its data. So the elements of an array or vector of `std::array` need not be contiguous. They would be in the same block, but there could be gaps.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` actually is `std::array<U,1>`You should be able to do this with template deduction and overloading:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> myFunc()
{ return {T{1}}; }

template <typename T>
void myOtherFunc(std::vector<T>)
{ cout << "not an array\n"; }

template <typename T, size_t N>
void myOtherFunc(std::vector<std::array<T,N>>)
{ cout << "an array\n"; }
```

Then calling it like this:

```
myOtherFunc(myFunc<int>()); //prints "not an array"
myOtherFunc(myFunc<std::array<int,1>>()); //prints "an array"
```